# I have an application error when trying to deploy to Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I keep getting an application error whenever I try to deploy to the Heroku website for my code. It builds perfectly fine whenever I deploy from the Heroku website or command line in VS Code, but I keep getting an error and the code I have for the website won't show up. I will include my build logs. Please and thank you for any help.

[Logs part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5TfF.jpg)

[Logs part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A01lf.jpg)

[Logs part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl9Xn.jpg)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5uG.jpg)

Comment: Does it work if you run the app locally with `heroku local`?

Comment: No it doesn't run locally